# How can I resolve HTML validation errors when using Facebook Comments?

Tags: html, facebook, validation

I am trying to validate my document that has the following facebook comments tag

```
<fb:comments width="425"></fb:comments>
```

I am getting validation error:

> Line 333, Column 45: Element name
>   fb:comments cannot be represented as
>   XML 1.0.

```
Element fb:comments not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Joel

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an appropriate doctype.

This has been covered (for HTML docs) on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761622/new-facebook-like-button-html-validation

Comment: Even with the appropriate doctype facebook comments will not validate as valid XHTML HTML or any type of HTML.  They are just not standard tags.  In your case, dont worry about it, because they are automatically parsed and fixed by facebook plugins on the page.